# How to change origin of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I´m currently making a card game, and it involves a card being enlarged.

The problem is that the origin.x and y is at the top left corner of the image, which results in that the image is being enlarged at the bottom left

I´m trying to figure out how to change the origin.x and origin.y to be in the center of the UIImageView and not the top left corner, so that the image stretches out to every corner instead of one. Sorry for the bad english, but thanks =)

Comment: Not entirely sure I'm understanding correctly, but it sounds like your UIImage's image file is too small to fill your UIImageView so you're unable to stretch it in the way that you like. The origin wouldn't be the issue in that case.

Comment: In Flash SC6 you can change the registration point, that´s what I am trying to do here

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't understand your question. Could you post the code where you stretch the image? Even if the origin is at the top left corner, you can still stretch the image out at every corner if you code it properly.

Comment: Well it´s not the enlarging part which is the problem, it´s the way it gets bigger. As you can see here - [Gyazo](http://gyazo.com/2232627aa6163c368ab9dfa5d29f7bfa)

 I´m trying to get the bottom option

Comment: I 100% understand that... But it would really help if you post your code. Basically, you're going to need to adjust your origin, width and height at the same time to get the effect you're looking for. If you post your code, I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to set the anchor point in the middle of the UIImageView instead of the default top-left.

```
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
```

Doing this however will also change the position of the image so that it is centered on the current position.

An alternate option is to offset the position by half the number of points you are increasing the size by. E.g. if the imageview is 100x100 and you are increasing the size to 150x150, adjust the position by -25,-25. This won't work too well if you are animating the resize.

Comment: I´ve tried that, but the image is still where it was before I added anchorpoint

Comment: How are you increasing the size of the imageview? If you use CGAffineTransformMakeScale it should scale from the center.

Comment: Thanks @JoGoFo! Exactly what I was looking for =) CGAffineTransformMakeScale